# Example of how a ring can have more than one maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I found the definition of the (Jacobson) radical interesting. It says: "Let $R$ be a ring. The *(Jacobson) radical* denoted rad$(R)$ is the intersection of all the maximal ideals of $R$.

I want to better wrap my mind around this definition because apriori, I couldn't imagine how a ring can have more than one maximal ideal. When I think of rings and ideals, I imagine this chain: $I_1\subset I_2\subset \cdots I_n\subset R$ where $I_n$ is max.

But say $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $I=(6)$, then as $(2)\supset(6)$ and $(3)\supset (6)$ where $(2), (3)$ are maximal, then is this a valid example of how a ring can have multiple maximal ideals? Secondly, is a generalization of this that rad$(\mathbb{Z})=\cap\{(p)|p \,\,prime\}$?

Comment: Yeah, the example with $\mathbb{Z}$ works. If you only have one maximal ideal, this is a local ring.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{rad}(\mathbf Z)=\{0\}$. What you you wrote is not even an ideal. of $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for pointing that $rad(R)$ should be an ideal.

Comment: Were you thinking maximal mean the same thing as maximum or something?  "Having nothing above" is not the same thing as "everything is below" because the ideals are generally not linearly ordered.

Comment: @rschwieb, in some sense yes. I was thinking of the maximal ideal to be the leading ("largest") ideal that isn't equal to the ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed $\mathbb{Z}$ has many maximal ideals, namely the $(p)$ where $p$ is prime. Actually, having only one maximal ideal is a very strong property, called being a *local* ring.

You are correct that $rad(\mathbb{Z})=\bigcap \{(p)|p \text{ prime}\}$, and this actually means that $rad(\mathbb{Z})=\{0\}$, because no non-zero integer is divisible by all primes.

Comment: Yes! I did miss the intersection--just edited it .

Comment: It is not true that $(p) \cap (q)=0$ when $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Indeed, $(2) \cap (3)=(6)$. The reason $\operatorname{rad}(\mathbb{Z})=0$ is that no nonzero integer can be divisible by every prime. I also don't understand the remark about the intersection: $\bigcap_{p \mbox{ prime}} (p)$ and $\bigcap \{(p) \mid p \mbox{ prime}\}$ seem to be slightly different notations for the same thing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are of course right about the intersection, I just completely blinked. Also I had actually not seen the small intersection sign before the set, I am used to bigcap being used in that case and did not notice the simple sap.